# How to send mail with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

When a customer buys an item, the button should send an email to the website owner. Here is the code I currently have:

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtpout.europe.secureserver.net", 80);

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@furkantellioglu.com      ", "Password");
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Body = "Bekleyen Siparişleriniz Bulunmakta Lütfen Kontrol Ediniz.";
        mail.Subject = "Dermabon Web Satış";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mail.From = new MailAddress("info@furkantellioglu.com", "Sipariş");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@furkantellioglu.com"));
        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("f.tellioglu@gmail.com"));

        smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

But when I run it I get this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sunucu güvenli bağlantıları desteklemiyor.
```

Any ideas on what this means?

Comment: run this from cmd promt:- telnet smtpout.europe.secureserver.net 80 and check it is connecting or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try changing

```
 smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

to

```
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
```

a similar thread has been discussed on this forum which might help you [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773810/system-net-mail-smtpexception-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-t)

Answer (score 0):

the error message means the server does not support secure connections. Your are using enable ssl but sending to port 80 so there could be a conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a port error, try using changing 
`EnableSsl=false;` and or `UseDefaultCredentials = true;` or use `port 25`