# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

```
 //less security is enabled
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("pk.uzikhan@gmail.com", "*********");
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Send(mm);
//       ViewBag.Message = "Email sent.";
return Ok("email sent");
```

Comment: `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false` FYI, Google seems to make a breaking change to gmail every few months.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could read the official document about SmtpClient:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials?view=netframework-4.8#system-net-mail-smtpclient-credentials

you could see the Remark on the "SmtpClient.Credentials Property":

To use your default network credentials, you can set the UseDefaultCredentials to true instead of setting this property.

Make sure you are using the correct account and password.Also, don't forget set your google account as below:

[image]
[image]
I tested with the codes:

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
            mail.To.Add(emailaddress);
            mail.Subject = "Hi";
            mail.Body = "Doc";
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;            
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(emailaddress, password);
            SmtpServer.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;            
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

The result:
[image: result]

You could see the explain of the error message in this case:
[System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773810/system-net-mail-smtpexception-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-t)

Comment: It help me alot Thanks alot, It work like a charm :).

Comment: It will no longer work as less secure app feature is now removed by Google. It's also clearly visible in the image shared by responder.

Comment: This will be valid solution after May 30, 2022. [App Password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169647/6845412)

Answer (score -1):

Seems google has disabled the Less Secure app access, at least I couldn't find a way to enable it. But it does have the "app password", which creates a password to be used by your apps, instead of your regular pwd.

https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

After I created this pwd and used it in my windows service, I stopped getting that exception and got the email working.